# Java concurrency code improvement ideas

Tags: java, concurrency

I've recently given a coding interview on a Java concurrency task and unfortunately didn't get the job.  The worst part is I've given my best but now I'm not even sure where went wrong.  Can anyone help give me some ideas about things I can improve on below code?  Thanks

The question is pretty vague.  Given 4 generic interface which on a high level divides a task into small pieces, work on each piece and combine the partial result into final result, I'm asked to implement the central controller piece of the interface.  The only requirement is to use concurrency in the partial result processing and "code must be production quality"

My code is as below (the interfaces was given).  I did put in a lot of comment to explain my assumptions which are removed here

```
// adding V,W in order to use in private fields types
public class ControllerImpl<T, U, V, W> implements Controller<T, U> {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerImpl.class);

    private static int BATCH_SIZE = 100;

    private Preprocessor<T, V> preprocessor;
    private Processor<V, W> processor;
    private Postprocessor<U, W> postprocessor;

    public ControllerImpl() {
        this.preprocessor = new PreprocessorImpl<>();
        this.processor = new ProcessorImpl<>();
        this.postprocessor = new PostprocessorImpl<>();
    }

    public ControllerImpl(Preprocessor preprocessor, Processor processor, Postprocessor postprocessor) {
        this.preprocessor = preprocessor;
        this.processor = processor;
        this.postprocessor = postprocessor;
    }

    @Override
    public U process(T arg) {
        if (arg == null) return null;

        final V[] parts = preprocessor.split(arg);
        final W[] partResult = (W[]) new Object[parts.length];

        final int poolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();  
        final ExecutorService executor = getExecutor(poolSize);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < parts.length) {
            final List<Callable<W>> tasks = IntStream.range(i, i + BATCH_SIZE)
                .filter(e -> e < parts.length) 
                .mapToObj(e -> (Callable<W>) () -> partResult[e] = processor.processPart(parts[e])) 
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            i += tasks.size();

            try {
                logger.info("invoking batch of {} tasks to workers", tasks.size());
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                final List<Future<W>> futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks); 
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                logger.info("done batch processing took {} ms", end - start);
                for (Future future : futures) {
                    future.get();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error("{}", e);// have comments to explain better handling according to real business requirement 
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                logger.error("error: ", e);
            }
        }

        MoreExecutors.shutdownAndAwaitTermination(executor, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return postprocessor.aggregate(partResult);
    }

    private ExecutorService getExecutor(int poolSize) {
        final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat("Processor-%d")
            .setDaemon(true)
            .build();
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(), threadFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be one for [codereview.se]

Comment: This would be one for Nightmarish Java Interview Questions as well.

Comment: @Compass - Seriously. This must have come right before the "cavity-search" phase of the interview.

Comment: "Write me production quality code in 15 minutes" = Bad Idea.

Answer (score 5):

So, if I understand correctly, you have a Preprocessor that takes a T and splits it into an array of V[]. Then you have a processor which transforms a V into a W. And then a postprocessor which transforms a W[] into a U, right? And you must assemble those things.

First of all, arrays and generics really don't match together, so it's really bizarre for those methods to return arrays rather than lists. For production-quality code, generic arrays shouldn't be used.

So, to recap:

```
T --> V1 --> W1 --> U
      V2 --> W2
      .      .
      .      .
      Vn --> Wn
```

So you could do this:

```
V[] parts = preprocessor.split(t);
W[] transformedParts = 
    (W[]) Arrays.stream(parts) // unchecked cast due to the use of generic arrays
                .parallel() // this is where concurrency happens
                .map(processor::processPart)
                .toArray();
U result = postProcessor.aggregate(transformedParts);
```

If you use lists instead of arrays, and write it as a single line:

```
U result = 
    postProcessor.aggregate(
        preprocessor.split(t)
                    .parallelStream()
                    .map(processor::processPart)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Isn't parallel steam using a common forkjoinpool therefore unable to control how many thread is available or what other tasks are sharing the same pool? Also by "production quality" I was so convinced Future has to have a place in this in order to retrieve exception or am I on the wrong path?

Comment: Reg. the common pool, yes, but that's not necessarily a bad thing. And you can always submit your task to a custom pool if needed. Pre-optimizing is always a bad idea, especially for such a generic task and so few information about the context. Reg. exceptions, if this is supposed to be generic, there's no way you can correctly deal with unexpected exceptions without just throwing. Ignoring them and passing an incomplete array of W to the postprocessor, leading to an incorrect result rather than an exception signalling there was a problem.

Comment: Anyway, your solution has several other problems: creating and shutting down a new thread pool each time for example, or making strong assumptions for a generic process (like the size of the pool, making threads daemon, etc.). It's also much more complex than it needs to be. The split in batches just adds complexity for nothing, IMO. I would strive for a simple, readable solution, and tweak after measurements are done, **if needed**.